# How read elements from ArrayList<List<LatLng>>

Tags: java, android

I'm working with Android Studio and I have the following code in a public class named Coordenadas

```
public class Coordenadas {
    public ArrayList<List<LatLng>> getArrayPerimetro() {
        ArrayList<List<LatLng>> getArrayPrueba= new ArrayList<>();
        getArrayPrueba.add(0,PolyUtil.decode("xbgrEl}jcJaAgYjUq@Dd[oSK"));
        getArrayPrueba.add(1,PolyUtil.decode("zxnqElyyeJcC_JxFwE~BlIuFhF"));
        return getArrayPrueba;
    }
}
```

In MainActiviy I have this code. I know that this is not the correct way to read each element from the array. This is something I am trying to modify from an old code, but what would be the correct way to read each element.

```
    public ArrayList<List<LatLng>> perimetroArray;

    perimetroArray = newClassObj.getArrayPerimetro();
    Polygon polygon2 = googleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
            .clickable(true)
            .strokeColor(0x7700ff00)
            .add(perimetroArray.toArray(new LatLng[0])));
```

Could anyone help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here I am again. Sorry for the inconvenience, I found the answer by myself, but I'll publish it anyway, I hope the information will be useful to others. The correct way to read each element in the array is as follows:

```java
perimetroArray = newClassObj.getArrayPerimetro();
Polygon polygon2 = googleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
    .clickable(true)
    .strokeColor(0x7700ff00)
    .add(perimetroArray.get(1).toArray(new LatLng[0]))); <<--- get(N) where N is the index number from the array
```